# NSPredicate not working if search string contains left "(" and right ")" brackets

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, nspredicate

I am using NSPredicate to search contains from coredata. 
But Some records contains left and right brackets.
Example

productName = "Product (Product1)"
And I tried to filter data by prodcuctName then getting 0 results.

```
   self.productName = @"Product (Product1)";
   [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"productName MATCHES[cd] \"%@\"",self.productName]];
```

Please advice me to fix this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why do you place quotes around `%@` in your format string?

Comment: Without Quotes also not working.

Comment: I didn't expect it to.  However, I'd be surprised if it worked with *any* search string with those quotes in place.

Comment: Anyway, you have to escape the parentheses in the search string.

Comment: Now fixed my issue. MATCHES replaced by LIKE keyword. coz For search result MATCHES not required for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I replaced MATCHES keyword by LIKE.

And now NSPredicate working fine.
MATCHES is compare left/right expression using regex-style comparison according to ICU v3 (for more details see the ICU User Guide for [Regular Expressions](http://icu.sourceforge.net/userguide/regexp.html)).

And LIKE is simply compare same as "==".